# Touch Bar icons not showing for Android Studio after update

Tags: android-studio, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm using a MacBook for the first time.

I had Android Studio 4.0 or 4.1 (I think) installed. It used to show me all the icons in the Touch Bar like the green run icon and the debug icons so I could use them directly from there. Even when in debug mode I used to get all the icons for stepping over or stepping into code.

After that I updated Android Studio 2-3 times and I am currently on Android Studio 4.2.1 and it has stopped showing any of the Touch Bar icons for Android Studio since the first time I updated. There are times when debugging that the debugging icons show for a while and then suddenly disappear. I'm facing this issue only with Android Studio.

According to another answer online, I am supposed to have a folder for Touch Bar (Settings) under Android Studio: Preferences > Menu and Toolbars but I don't have and folder for Touch Bar Settings there.

Can any one help me resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I’m having the issue too, on Android Studio 4.2. Not sure if this is an AS bug.

Comment: I think it is an AS bug. The Touch Bar works fine on my Intellij Idea IDE. I think it should work well on Android Studio 4.0 or 4.1 but I don't feel like downgrading

Comment: I found this on reddit and tried but to no avail, may it helps? https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/n3q0vd/fix_for_android_studio_touch_bar_functions_on_m1/

Comment: I've set the touch bar to display function keys, it's more useful that way for now..

Comment: @KenIchi I tried that link and later realised I have an Intel Mac. I'm gonna set it to display function keys too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved after I upgraded to

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922

An interesting thing about Android Studio Artic Fox is that it has changed the versioning scheme to match that of it's parent product, the Intellij IDEA 2020.3.1. So rather than Android Studio 4.3 it is now Android Studio 2020.3.1 with code name Artic Fox. This will keep the versioning schemes systematic.

There are a lot of cool feature updates too.

Check more at this link [Android Studio Artic Fox release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#arctic-fox)

Answer (score 1):

answer in https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

To resolve this issue, revert any customizations you have made to those buttons as follows:

Select File > Settings (or Android Studio > Preferences on macOS).
On the left of the window, navigate to Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars.
On the right side of the window, navigate to Main Toolbar > Toolbar Run Actions and select Run/Debug.
Near the top of the window, click Revert.  and select Restore Run/Debug.
Click OK. You should now see the missing buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: Hey Hakan, I've tried this but it doesn't help because there's nothing wrong with the toolbar. The issue is that the Touch Bar doesn't display the toolbar icons.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Frameworks/nst.framework/
cd ~/Library/Frameworks/nst.framework/
ln -s path/to/android/studio/install/Contents/bin/libnst64.dylib nst
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. AS 4.2.2, MBP 2018 (Intel) with Big Sur 11.4. Even restarting the computer doesn't help.

Comment: Make sure you enter the correct path for Android Studio. If it's inside your global Applications folder, the path in the final command should be /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/libnst64.dylib